# Do dplyr functions on a database tbl execute locally or remotely?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I've been using dplyr for a bit locally and I've found it a very powerful tool. One thing that gets showcased in a lot of the intro talks I've found is how you can use it to operate on a database table "to only work with the data you want" via its aggregation functions, `summarize`, `mutate`, etc. I understand how it translates those into sql statements, but not so much other operations.

For example, if I wanted to work on a database table as a `tbl`, and I wanted to run a function on the result of my pipeline through `do()`, such as `glm`, would `glm` be transported to the database somehow to be run there, or is the data necessarily downloaded (in whatever reduced form) and then `glm` is run locally?

Depending on the size of the table in question, this is an important distinction. Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the database [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html)?

Comment: Yes, as with most tutorials it focuses on the connection and aggregation, not arbitrary computation on results. It does say that math functions, e.g. atanh, are passed through as the database supports them, but doesn't address the question of arbitrary R functions.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm confused because SQL data bases aren't generally able to somehow fit arbitrary R models. (There are some R embeddings in some databases, but I don't think dplyr talks to them.) And the lazyness section of that vignette covers everything that I would have expected a db to do. So the short answer is no, you cannot just fit a model in the db with dplyr.

Comment: The reason I ask is I'm considering writing a connect for IBM Netezza databases, and that already provides a means to run R code 'inside the box' as one of its advanced analytics features. If this functionality doesn't exist (and I agree, I wouldn't expect it to for arbitrary mysql or whatever) then I would gain nothing from connecting dplyr and shouldn't bother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any R analyses, calls to `glm()`, are run locally.  As @joran commented above, the [databases vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html), [introductory documentation](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html), [development information](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr), and many you can find on using `dplyr` are useful in learning how certain operations are converted to SQL and executed on the DB system.  I believe you can induce certain bottlenecks by  introducing R-specific analyses in the middle of a chain of operations when finishing DB-capable operations first might be more efficient.